# Populate a TTreeView With Directory Tree And Filtering

Tags: delphi, treeview, tree, lazarus

On a Lazarus 0.9.28.2 project I have a `TTreeView`, with the name `DirTree` on my Form(`frmConvert`), but I want to populate it with all the directory tree, since `C:\`.

Like this:
[C:\ Directory Tree http://i.imagehost.org/0185/cdirtree.png](http://i.imagehost.org/0185/cdirtree.png)

And when the user select the directory, in the second `TTreeView`, with the name `FileTree`, appear all the files in that directory, but filtered to show only PDFs.

Also I want help to put these icons, because is very nice to be more organized and friendly for the end-user.

**Questions**

- How can I populate the first TTreeView(`DirTree`) with all the directorys, like in the image?
- How can I populate the second TTreeview(`FileTree`) with the files on the directory selected on `DirTree`?
- How can I set a icon for each folder(only folders) on `DirTree`?

Comment: The image was linked to an outside third-party source, which appears to no longer be available...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code to populate the dirTree  (REVISED)**

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  FileAttrs: Integer;
  theRootNode : tTreeNode;
  theNode : tTreeNode;
begin
   FileAttrs := faDirectory;     // Only care about directories
   theRootNode := DirTree.Items.AddFirst(nil,'c:\');
   if FindFirst('c:\*.*', FileAttrs, sr) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        if (sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = sr.Attr then
        begin
            theNode := dirTree.Items.AddChild(theRootNode,sr.name);
            AddDirectories(theNode,'c:\'+sr.Name);
        end;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
//    DirTree.FullExpand;
end;
```

****Code to populate FileTree (REVISED) ****

```
procedure TForm1.FilteredTV(theDir: string;ext:String;startNode:tTreeNode);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  FileAttrs: Integer;
  theNode : tTreeNode;
begin
   if copy(ext,1,1)<>'.' then ext := '.'+ext;
   FileAttrs := faAnyfile;
   if startNode = nil then
       StartNode := FileTree.Items.AddFirst(nil,theDir);
   if FindFirst(theDir+'\*.*', FileAttrs, sr) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        if (sr.Attr=faDirectory) and (copy(sr.Name,1,1)<>'.') then
            begin
                theNode := FileTree.Items.AddChild(StartNode,sr.name);
                theNode.ImageIndex := 0;   // Use folder image for directories
                FilteredTV(theDir+'\'+sr.name,ext,theNode);
            end
        else
            if ((sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = sr.Attr) and (ExtractFileExt(sr.name)=ext)
            then
            begin
                theNode := FileTree.Items.AddChild(StartNode,sr.name);
                theNode.ImageIndex := -1;   // No image for files
            end;

      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
    FileTree.FullExpand;
end;
```

**Additional procedure to add to form**

```
procedure TForm1.AddDirectories(theNode: tTreeNode; cPath: string);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  FileAttrs: Integer;
  theNewNode : tTreeNode;
begin
   FileAttrs := faDirectory;     // Only care about directories
   if FindFirst(cPath+'\*.*', FileAttrs, sr) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        if  ((sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = sr.Attr) and (copy(sr.Name,1,1) <> '.')
        then
        begin
            theNewNode := dirTree.Items.AddChild(theNode,sr.name);
            AddDirectories(theNewNode,cPath+'\'+sr.Name);
        end;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
end;
```

You need to add an image list to your form, add a folder icon to it (there is one in the borland common files) and then associated the image list with the directory treeview **and the filetree treeview**

**EXAMPLE OF HOW TO CALLED FILTEREDTV procedure**

Attach the following code to the OnClick event of the directory tree

```
procedure TForm1.DirTreeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cBuild : string;
  theNode : tTreeNode;
begin
    if DirTree.Selected <> nil then
    begin
        theNode := DirTree.Selected;
        cBuild := theNode.Text;
        while theNode.Parent <> nil do
        begin
            cBuild := theNode.Parent.Text+'\'+cBuild;
            theNode := theNode.Parent;
        end;
        cBuild := stringReplace(cBuild,'\\','\',[rfReplaceAll]);
        FilteredTV(cBuild,'pdf',nil);
    end;

end;
```

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question.   You are going to need a recursive call for each directory...   Performance wise, that could slow down the tree logic substantially, since you now need to scan the entire structure of the hard disk.   I'll adapt the code above for you...

Comment: See the revisions, they should give you what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks very much! But how I can use the `TForm1.FilteredTV`?

Comment: **I mean:** How can I execute the procedure?

Comment: I added an example of how to call the FilteredTV procedure based on the folder the user clicks on in the DirTree view

Comment: Thanks very very much **Sparky** for your very hard work to help me!

Comment: This: `if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then begin` should block around `if (sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = sr.Attr then begin` in the `FormClick` procedure, to exclude the `.` and `..` values - this procedure actually loads data under these nodes. Don't think you want that.

Comment: It also appears to be excluding a number of directories for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge - That's because multiple small issues:
#1. "(sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = sr.Attr)" - this only allows exact match - excludes valid folders with other attribute bits set = should be "(sr.Attr and FileAttrs) = FileAttrs)" (so readonly, hidden/etc folders allowed too).
#2. "(copy(sr.Name,1,1) <> '.')" excludes any dir starting with dot = should be as in your comment.