# How do I populate a Treeview via FTP

Tags: delphi, ftp, treeview, indy

**Scenario**

I'm trying to duplicate the standard way to fill a Treeview with directories/folders from a folder structure, starting at the root, but using IdFTP to get the structure from a remote server instead of my local hard drive. I'd like the result to look similar to clients like Filezilla.

I used [this](https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=400) reasonably standard code from the Swiss Delphi Centre (which works to display my hard drive's structure) and then modified it to use IdFTP.ChangeDir(Directory) and IdFTP.List    instead of FindFirst() and FindNext().

**Problem**

I seem to have got myself in a muddle as it is not correctly 'unwinding' the recursion so that once it traverses down the /cpanel/cashes/config directories on the remote server it doesn't return and traverse all the other directories hanging off the root but exits the procedure without displaying anything else. Also it doesn't seem to show all the top level folders but this could be simply due to the order that IdFTP.List returns them in

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong here?

If you can also tell me how I should get the root (/) shown as well that would be very helpful

(I've commented out displaying non directories as I only want folders at this stage)

**What I expected to see**  Copied from Filezilla

[image]

**What I did see** Using a Ttreeview in Delphi

[image]

My Code

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var StartingDir : string;
begin
TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
    StartingDir :=    '/';
    Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    TreeView1.Items.Clear;
    FTPconnect;  //procedure to connect to remote server
    GetDirectories(TreeView1, StartingDir, nil, True);
    FTPDisconnect; //procedure to disconnect from remote server
finally
    TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
end;

procedure TForm2.GetDirectories(Tree: TTreeView; Directory: string; Item: TTreeNode; IncludeFiles: Boolean);
var
  ItemTemp: TTreeNode;
  DirItemType : TIdDirItemType  ;
  Filename , NewStartingDirectory: string;
  i : Integer;
begin
  Tree.Items.BeginUpdate;
  IdFTP.ChangeDir(Directory);
  IdFTP.List;      //get directory of remote folder
  i:=0;
  repeat
     DirItemType := IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].ItemType;
     Filename := IdFTP.DirectoryListing[I].FileName;
     If (DirItemType = ditDirectory) and (Filename <> '.') and (Filename <> '..')then
        begin
        if DirItemType = ditDirectory then
              Item := Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, Filename);
        ItemTemp := Item.Parent;
        if Directory = '/' then
            NewStartingDirectory := Directory  + Filename
        else
            NewStartingDirectory := Directory + '/' +Filename;
        GetDirectories(Tree, NewStartingDirectory, Item, IncludeFiles);
        Item := ItemTemp;
        end
     else 
        if IncludeFiles then
           begin  //this bit commented out as we only want to see directories
//         if (Filename <> '.') and (Filename <> '..') then
//         Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, Filename);
           end;
     inc(i);
  until i = IdFTP.DirectoryListing.Count;
  Tree.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

**Swiss Delhpi Centre's code (for comparison)**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Path: string;
  Dir: string;
begin
  Dir := 'c:\temp';
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    TreeView1.Items.Clear;
    GetDirectories(TreeView1, Dir, nil, True);
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetDirectories(Tree: TTreeView; Directory: string; Item: TTreeNode; IncludeFiles: Boolean);
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  ItemTemp: TTreeNode;
begin
  Tree.Items.BeginUpdate;
  if Directory[Length(Directory)] <> '\' then Directory := Directory + '\';
  if FindFirst(Directory + '*.*', faDirectory, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory = faDirectory) and (SearchRec.Name[1] <> '.') then
      begin
        if (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory > 0) then
          Item := Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, SearchRec.Name);
        ItemTemp := Item.Parent;
        GetDirectories(Tree, Directory + SearchRec.Name, Item, IncludeFiles);
        Item := ItemTemp;
      end
      else if IncludeFiles then
        if SearchRec.Name[1] <> '.' then
          Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, SearchRec.Name);
    until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
  Tree.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

I've looked on SO  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830900/c-sharp-populate-treeview-with-ftp-server-directories) - too complicated and wrong language and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967359/populate-a-ttreeview-with-directory-tree-and-filtering) - similar to the Swiss Delphi Centre and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923193/list-all-files-from-online-ftp-directory-to-a-listview-c-sharp)  - wrong language and not sure what its doing.

if it's better to use a TlistView, can you please show me the equivalent code to use that instead?

Comment: You must store the content of `IdFTP.DirectoryListing` in your own variable - otherwise the next call to `IdFTP.List()` will change it **for every iteration** of the recursion, no matter where you currently are. If `/.cpanel/caches/config` has no or one entry then `IdFTP.DirectoryListing.Count` will be `0` or `1` for everything and exit your loop exactly with that logic.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thank you. I added  a variable `TheDirectoryListing : TIdFTPListItems;`, added  `directoryListing := IdFTP.DirectoryListing;` immediately after `IdFTP.List` and changed refernces to `IdFTP.DirectoryListing` to `TheDirectoryListing;` but it made no difference, I got the same output. Sort of as I expected as I'm still calling `IdFTP.list` every iteration. I must have misunderstood, please can you elaborate.

Comment: You just copied a reference, not the content. Alternatively iterate over `IdFTP.DirectoryListing` without recursion and store only folders into a `TStringList` - afterwards you can recurse over your own list.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you tell me how to copy the content of IdFTP.DirectoryListing?

Comment: Just like you do it now, but instead of adding a new tree node and re-calling your own method you add the folder as text to your list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do I correctly do `directoryListing := IdFTP.DirectoryListing;` but copy the contents of `IdFTP.DirectoryListing;`  instead of a reference to it, as you suggested (I'd like to try that first before rewriting it all to do away with the recursion by storing folders etc.)

Comment: The same way you would **copy** the content of an object (f.e. a `TStringList`) - either search for that or make it a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

- I made the `TIdFTP` variable a parameter, since `TTreeView` was also one and it should be done consistently, not archaic.
- Using `for` loops instead of `repeat until`.
- Eliminating `IncludeFiles` when it wasn't used anyway.
- Eliminating weird logic to always get the new TreeNode's parent.
- Not locking the TreeView anymore - do this once before calling this method and unlock it after calling - otherwise you do that dozens of times in vain.
- Basic logic is as I wrote in the comments:

  1. Store all folder strings into your own list and avoid recursion at this point.
  2. Fix the path to be concatenated once, not with every iteration of a loop.
  3. Go through that list to do the recursion - at this point the state of `FTP` is irrelevant and you won't mess up listings at different levels.
  4. Of course, release the created instance of the StringList.

```pascal
procedure TForm2.GetFolders
( Ftp: TIdFTP  // The source, from which we read the content
; Tree: TTreeView  // The destination, which we want to fill
; ParentNode: TTreeNode  // Node under which all new child nodes should be created
; Path: String  // Starting directory
);
var
    NewNode: TTreeNode;  // New child in the tree
    Filename: String;  // Check against unwanted folder entries
    i: Integer;  // Looping over both lists
    sl: TStringList;  // Collect folders only
begin
    FTP.ChangeDir( Path );
    FTP.List;  // Entire remote listing

    sl:= TStringList.Create;  // Collect all entries we're interested in
    try
        for i:= 0 to FTP.DirectoryListing.Count- 1 do begin  // For each entry
            Filename:= FTP.DirectoryListing[i].FileName;
            if  (FTP.DirectoryListing[i].ItemType= ditDirectory)  // Only folders
            and (Filename<> '.')
            and (Filename<> '..') then begin
                sl.Add( Filename );  // Only the name, not the full path
            end;
        end;

        // Do this only once
        if Path<> '/' then Path:= '/'+ Path+ '/';

        for i:= 0 to sl.Count- 1 do begin  // All collected folders
            NewNode:= Tree.Items.AddChild( ParentNode, sl[i] );  // Populate tree
            GetFolders( Ftp, Tree, NewNode, Path+ sl[i] );  // Recursion of folder name + current path
        end;
    finally
        sl.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Untested, but should compile.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to code that. Clearly I had to change the procedure prototype from `Procedure GetFolders; `to
`Procedure GetFolders ( FTP : TIdFTP; Tree : TTreeView; ParentNode :TTreeNode; Path: String );` but then this alternative method gave the desired result. I've accepted your answer as it answers the question in the title by introducing an additional step and I can see the logic of doing that. I'd still be interested though to see if it can be done using the reasonably standard algorithm in my post but using FTP methods instead if findfirst/findnext. - Maybe it can't.

Comment: I nowhere defined `procedure GetFolders;` without parameters (but yes: you have to declare it in your Form class, too). No, there's no "_first/next_", because you pull the entire list at once - that's how FTP works in contrast to file systems. It also wouldn't solve your misunderstanding that you operate globally on the same instance of the list instead of having separate list instances per recursion. Your whole problem is/was not being able to tell instances apart from references. Ask/search a question about that concept to get an answer.

Comment: I meant that your code has 'procedure TForm2.GetFolders;` at the top, without parameters but the recursive call to  it is `GetFolders( Ftp, Tree, NewNode, Path+ sl[i] );`, with four parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Look closer: there's no semicolon - the definition continues in the next lines. You also put `then begin` into multiple lines while I don't. There's no mandatory to stuff everything into one line. Alternatively explain me why lines 2-6 in my code don't raise questions on your side.